# Querystring parameter is not working in xml viewer web part

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, sharepoint-2010

There is a SharePoint webpage(pocwebpage.aspx) with XML Web Part on it and the XSLT and XML are linked on the web part. A Querystring parameter is trying to pass through URL on the XMLWeb Part page but it is not passed over XSLT during loading. The following are the data for your review,

### XML

```
<RootData>
<Employee>
 <Name>Ramesh</Name>
</Employee>
<Employee>
 <Name>Suresh</Name>
</Employee>
<Employee>
 <Name>Ganesh</Name>
</Employee>
</RootData>
```

### XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="param"/>
<xsl:template match="Employee">
Parameter : <xsl:value-of select="$param"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="RootData/Employee">
    Employee Name : <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

$param returns only empty string and not retrun the query paramvalue "discovery"

### Query string URL

http://sharepoint-server/sitename/pocwebpage.aspx?param=discovery

[image: XML Webpart]

Your help is very much appreciated and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a parameter you don't need `$`

```
<xsl:param name="param"/>
```

When you access this parameter you need `$`

```
<xsl:value-of select="$param"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried changing $ sign on the parameter but it is still showing empty value and the query string value is not passed over. Should I pass param explicitly and if so could you please help me out code snippet ?

Comment: @Smaug, actually I don't know how to pass parameter in sharepoint. anyway, the notation I provided above is correct way to work with parameters in XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not do this with XSL - it is rendered on server-side without any data provided about query URL.

The workaround is to get query parameters by JavaScript.